# Синхронизация мюьтекса - C++ Builder

Tags: c++

Помогите разобратся почему не выполняется условие во втором Timer2?
Принцип работы приложения такой: запускаем первое начинают работать часы...затем запускаем второе...часы там не работают так как запущены в перво приложении. Как только нажимаю кнопку в первом,часы останавливаются и начинают работать часы во втором.
Идея моя такая: Когда открывается форма на событие on create() создаётся мьютекс если он уже создан то ничего не происходит. Установлен второй таймер который работает всегда и проверяет есть ли мьютекс или нет. По нажатию на кнопку

```
TForm3 *Form3;
int s=0;
int m=0;
int h=0;
int x=0;
HANDLE H;
HANDLE hx;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm3::TForm3(TComponent* Owner)
: TForm(Owner)
```

{
}

```
     void __fastcall TForm3::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
     {
         Panel3->Caption=s;
          Panel2->Caption=m;
           Panel1->Caption=h;
            s++;
           if(s==60) {m++; s=0;}
          if(m==60) {h++; m=0;}
          if(h==24)  h=0;

         }
        void __fastcall TForm3::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)  
        {
               Timer1->Enabled=false;
              ReleaseMutex(H);
              CloseHandle(H); // удаляем мьютекс , а не освобождаем его
              Sleep(3000);
        }
           void __fastcall TForm3::Timer2Timer(TObject *Sender)
           {

               if (OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE, true, "MyMutex")) // есть? Значит,            другое приложение открыло диалог
               {
                    Panel4->Caption=x;
                     x++;
                 }
               else{
                    H=CreateMutex(NULL, true, "MyMutex");
                    Timer1->Enabled=true;
                   }
                 }
                void __fastcall TForm3::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
                  {
                       if(OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE, true, "MyMutex"))
                       {
                             Timer1->Enabled=false;;
                       }
                       else{
                            H=CreateMutex(NULL, true, "MyMutex");
                           }
                   }
```

Comment: У вас слетело форматирование кода, поправьте.

Comment: а зачем Вам мютекс? код то однопоточных.

Comment: такое условие задачи